# Spring Openid, OpenIDAuthenticationToken

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, openid

I am using Spring-Security's Openid for authentication using google. I want to recieve the email id from google server. so in my spring-security.xml i have set up

```
<attribute-exchange>
    <openid-attribute name="email" type="http://schema.openid.net/contact/email" required="true" />
    <openid-attribute name="name" type="http://schema.openid.net/namePerson/friendly" />
</attribute-exchange>
```

now I want to get it. I understand that the documentation tells us to use the following code.

```
OpenIDAuthenticationToken token = (OpenIDAuthenticationToken)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
List<OpenIDAttribute> attributes = token.getAttributes();
```

can anybody write me the code snippet to take out the email attribute using this code???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the list of attributes to find the email address, as [the OpenID sample application does](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/samples/openid/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/samples/openid/CustomUserDetailsService.java#L63).

Alternatively, you might want to follow the sample more closely and use a custom `UserDetailsService` which creates specialized `UserDetails` instance which you can then access elsewhere in your application.